# robobrowser to deal with response in json

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mechanize, robobrowser

I'm trying to programmably access a website

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
import sys

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open('https://test.com/login')
loginForm = browser.get_form()
loginForm['UserName']='username'
loginForm['Password']='*'
browser.submit_form(loginForm)
if browser.response.ok: 
   if browser.response.content[2]=='false':
       print browser.response.content[4]
       sys.exit(1)
```

website returned json format ( at least i think it's json), but i can't seems to find robobrowser api for dealing with json.

```
{"RedirectUrl":null,"IsSuccess":false,"Message":null,"CustomMessage":null,"Errors":[{"Key":"CaptchaValue","Value":["Your response did not match. Please try again."]}],"Messages":{},"HasView":true.......}
```

As you can see I want to test if "isSuccess", and print error message, how can I proceed in this case?

thanks

Comment: no one knows how to do this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution using json

```
json.load(StringIO(browser.response.content))
```

Answer (score 0):

and for python 3.x is functional

```
import io
import json

json.load(io.BytesIO(browser.response.content))
```

Comment: Try to give some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @Mikev sorry for my late answer. I'm using python 3.6 and I found from [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) that


> The StringIO and cStringIO modules are gone. Instead, import the io module and use io.StringIO or io.BytesIO for text and data respectively.


So I tried `io.StringIO` and got an error:
```
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

and with `io.BytesIO` I was succeed.